# How to only "show" getElementsByClassName on each individual click

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

```js
function zxcv(el) {
el.style.display = "none";
el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere")[0].style.display = 'block';
return false;
}
```

The code above wasn't what I needed as it would only activate one occurrence of the elements.

The code below isn't what I need as it only activates all occurrences of the elements on click

```js
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    var elements = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("thishere");
    for(var i in elements) {
           elements[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please see JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f484126/aspnetny/) for HTML and where I'm currently at with it (please note, I would change the onLoad option to No wrap but JSFiddle seems to have removed Frameworks and Extensions, or at least I can't see it :/, so this I suspect is why the "answer" isn't being revealed. When I test myself the answers do show).

My expertise is very limited and I'm stuck; I only want the element which is clicked to "show", not all once. Please help!

For Example:

One + One = Two

Two + Two = Four

if 'One +One =' is clicked, then 'Four' wouldn't show, just 'Two'

Comment: Your `html` provided in `fiddle` and your attempt does not match.. There isn't any `parentNode` right?

Comment: It is consistent, even if it is consistently incorrect! I did state my expertise was limited hence why I was asking for help. I tried to be as useful as I could be and explained the process I'd been through. I think to downgrade me for that is rather harsh given the criteria for doing so is "The question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear/not useful".

Comment: And for your kind information I haven't down voted you and it's very sad thing that people judge very easily without even being sure that a guy who has commented himself has down voted.. I commented to clarify what's the actual question since I didn't understand it from your post so that I could help you in a better way.. I meant no offense..

Comment: Thank you - I did assume it was you so my apologies.

Comment: Never mind.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to get next sibling. Don't need to use iteration.

```js
function zxcv(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    var elements = el.nextElementSibling;
    elements.style.display = 'block';   
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a class="mathslink" href="#" rel="nofollow" onClick="zxcv(this)">One + One Equals</a>
<div class="thishere" style="display:none;"><span class="mathsanswer"><strong>Two</strong></span></div>

<a class="mathslink" href="#" rel="nofollow" onClick="zxcv(this)">Two + Two Equals</a>
<div class="thishere" style="display:none;"><span class="mathsanswer"><strong>Four</strong></span></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I know now that I should be using nextElementSibling. However, when I tested and click the link to go to a URL, the "answer" doesn't show. There is only a blank space where the original link was.

Comment: @f484126 If I understand right you want to keep the data and redirect to another page to display the result?

Comment: sorry I'm being unclear. I actually want it to behave like your example, but I cannot get it to do so. I changed slightly to  href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" instead of just href="#". When I click Two + Two Equals I want the Answer to take the place of the Question. When I click however, there is only a blank space. I don't know why :(

Comment: @f484126 Then copy my html in your code. I removed `target="_blank"` from your code and use `href="#"` in `a` elements.

Comment: I know you have, but I want it to go to an external URL. Can your code work with an external URL or not? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @f484126 There are some rules you have to follow in web development. You can't use the above code the way you describe. For example you have to send the data in external URL as query parameters for example.

Comment: Then unfortunately this is not the code I'm looking for. Thanks for your help though all the same :)

Comment: @f484126 You are welcome. Keep in mind though SO isn't a site to build an application for you. We are here just to provide some help :)